# nginx keep port number when 301 redirecting

Tags: nginx, server, vagrant, http-status-code-301

I'm trying to collapse a second brand of a web app into the first brand and use 301 redirects to redirect any lingering traffic. The server is running in a Vagrant box forwarding on port 8001. I would like to have:

Instead of **https://local-dev-url:8001/foo/(anything)** 301 to **https://local-dev-url:8001/(anything)**

Instead of **https://local-dev-url:8001/adminfoo/(anything)** 301 to **https://local-dev-url:8001/admin/(anything)**.

Here's what I have:

```
    location ~ /foo/?(.*)$ {
        return 301 $1/;
    }

    location ~ /adminfoo/?(.*)$ {
        return 301 admin/$1/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 443;
        proxy_set_header Authorization $http_authorization;
        proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
        proxy_redirect http:// $scheme://;
    }

    location /admin/ {
        alias /hostonly/path/to/admin/stuff/;
    }
```

However, instead of redirecting **https://local-dev-url:8001/foo/** to **https://local-dev-url:8001/** it is 301ing to **https://local-dev-url//** instead. (No port number, extra slash.) I've seen answers that hard-code the URL of the redirect, but since I work with a lot of other devs and we all have unique local dev URLs, the only consistent part is the :8001 port number.

Is there a way to configure the 301 to work as desired?

Comment: What port is this server listening on? Are you forwarding 8001 to 80?

Comment: @RichardSmith port 443, not 80.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If `nginx` is not listening on port 8001, it cannot know which port to use in the redirect. You will need to specify it explicitly:

```
location ~ /foo(.*)$ {
    return 301 $scheme://$http_host$1;
}
location ~ /adminfoo(.*)$ {
    return 301 $scheme://$http_host/admin$1;
}
```

The `$http_host` variable consists of the hostname and port from the original request. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_http_) for details.

Comment: I ran into this issue when using port forwarding using `docker`. The same concept applies here. `nginx` inside of the container is listening on port `80` and the `docker` container's port is forwarded, so `nginx` will use `80` when redirecting.

Comment: :) Awesome ! ty

Answer (score 0):

For me, editing the following lines in `proxy.conf` to look like this, did the trick:

```
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
```