# Also pass the port in an Nginx path?

Tags: docker, nginx, redirect

Total Nginx noob here and I have what is probably a dirt simple issue, but I need my `Return` to also include the port.

For example, when I pass the URL:

`https://my.domain.rocks:3332/ombi`

... that redirects me to the same domain, *minus* the port, plus the newly appended trailing slash, like this:

`https://my.domain.rocks/ombi/`

What I *need* is for it to keep the port as well, like this:

`https://my.domain.rocks:3332/ombi/`

... note that it's identical to the originally passed URL, but keeps the port, plus the trailing slash.

The LetsEncrypt container I'm using comes with some sample reverse proxy scripts, and for the ombi one that I'm using, the top block is the follow, which is not passing the port as I want:

```
location /ombi {
    return 301 $scheme://$host/ombi/;
}
```

I've tried changing it to:

```
return 301 $scheme://$host:$server_port/ombi/;
```

But it didn't do anything apparent.

Any one know how to do this?

Comment: As for the port part https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43397365/nginx-keep-port-number-when-301-redirecting should answer it. And the trailing slash is likely added by the redirect rule itself--there's a trailing slash there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution:

Instead of using `return`, do a `rewrite`:

```
rewrite [^/]$ $scheme://$http_host$uri/ permanent;
```