# Can't find nginx variable that contains the path portion of the uri

Tags: nginx, redirect, uri

I'm adding trailing slashes with a rewrite directive in NGINX. Currently I'm doing it like this:

```
# 301 Redirect for trailing slash
location ~ ^([^.]*[^/])$ {
    try_files $request_uri @addslash;
}

# 301 Redirect for trailing slash
location @addslash {
    return 301 $uri/$is_args$args;
}
```

It works, but only on port 80. Now I'm looking for a way to re-write the second part of this construct to forward to the correct port.

I found [this discussion that explains how to forward to the correct port](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43397988/10043870). But it doesn't forward the rest of the uri as it is. The part that comes after the port is not considered. For my construct, that would be [the "path" portion of the uri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier).

Which nginx variable contains only the path portion? Or alternatively everything that comes after the port in the uri?

And: Does anyone know a list of nginx variables with examples? [The one from the documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/varindex.html) doesn't really help in this case :-P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, for this particular problem I found the answer:

```
# 301 Redirect for trailing slash
location ~ ^([^.]*[^/])$ {
    try_files $request_uri @addslash;
}

# 301 Redirect for trailing slash
location @addslash {
    return 301 $scheme://$http_host$request_uri/$is_args$args;
}
```

$request_uri is the variable I was looking for. Turns out I was very close.

It would still be nice to have a list of nginx variables with examples as nginx seems to use different wordings than the uri specification.